# Servidor WildFly não está executando

Tags: java-ee

Estou com problema no meu servidor WildFly 15 e não estou conseguindo executar ele e nem subir nenhuma aplicação. Será que é problema com a nova versão do servidor? Segue abaixo o erro:

```
Failed to start service org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990
    at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:349)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

09:05:49,320 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
09:05:52,446 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.2.3.Final (Apache CXF 3.2.5.jbossorg-1) 
09:05:52,466 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990"}}
09:05:52,473 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:9990"}}
```

Comment: Essa é uma pregunta sobre programação?

Comment: na vdd estou com problema no meu servidor, ele não está inicializando

Answer (score 1):

No erro está falando que já tem um programa utilizando esse endereço/porta "localhost/127.0.0.1:9990".

Provavelmente já tem um wildifly startado, finalize todos os processos do wildifly e tente startar novamente.

No erro está falando que já tem um programa utilizando esse endereço/porta "localhost/127.0.0.1:9990".

Provavelmente já tem um wildifly startado, finalize todos os processos do wildifly e tente startar novamente.

**Como matar o processo:**
Se estiver utilizando o windows abra o CMD e digite netstat -a -n -o serão listadas as portas que estão sendo utilizadas, encontre a porta 9990 e copie o número do PID e digite kill [número do PID]. Feito isso você vai matar o processo que esta utilizando esta porta e poderá startar a aplicação novamente.

Comment: como que eu faço para finalizar todos os processor do servidor wildfly, vc poderia me falar pfv. Ainda estou começando nesse mundo da programação

Comment: qual servidor está utilzando

Comment: estou utilizando o wildfly, mas tbm existe dois servidores no meu eclipse. O tomcat e wildfly, acho que pode ser isso tbm que está dando ruim

Comment: um  teste que você pode fazer é finalizar os processo javaw.exe no gerenciador de processos do windows, mas pode ser que feche seu eclipse

Comment: como que eu faço isso?

Comment: Atualizei a respota

Comment: mano eu achei um outro comando, pq o eu não deu certo e coloquei esse aqui "taskkill -im  4192" e deu esse erro aqui no cmd e não funcionou:
ERRO: o processo com PID 4192 não pôde ser finalizado.
Razão: Acesso negado. OQ UE FAÇO MANINHO??